# Getting error when calling web-component created using LIT inside react component

Tags: reactjs, webpack, web-component, lit-element, lit

I am getting error when i am trying to use my custom webcomponent in react

> the following properties on element card will not trigger updates
> as expected because they are set using class fields: layout. Native
> class fields and some compiled output will overwrite accessors used
> for detecting changes. See https://lit.dev/msg/class-field-shadowing
> for more information.

```
import { html, LitElement } from 'lit';
import { customElement, property } from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('test-component')
export class TestComponent extends LitElement {
    @property() layout = '';
    render() {
        return html`this.layout`
    }
}
```

I have also gone through docs and used

```
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",{"legacy": true}],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", {"loose": true}],
```

in my babelrc, still when i call this web component, its giving error. what's going wrong here ?

Comment: i can't say if this'll fix your issue for sure but check the babel settings mentioned here: https://lit.dev/docs/components/decorators/#decorators-babel

Comment: Thank you it worked, i added version for decorator plugin

Comment: Could you please add what worked as an answer to close the question. Thank you so much!

Comment: sure I, updated version of "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators"
 ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {
    "version": "2018-09",
    "decoratorsBeforeExport": true
  }]

So basically version "2018-09" this plugin contains rules on how to transpile reactive properties